# git merge and different gitignore for each branch

Tags: git, merge, gitignore, git-flow

I have 2 branches, `develop` and `master`. The `master` branch should not contain some development files and tools that are store in a directory called `boilerplate`. So far, so good, since I can more or less, manage with the following differences in the `.gitignore` file, between branches.

### develop

```
# Dev tools
/html
/boilerplate/node_modules
/boilerplate/bower_components

/assets/dist/main.min.css
/assets/dist/main.min.js

.....
```

master

```
# Cleanup for live
/html
/boilerplate

/assets/dist/main.css
/assets/dist/main.js

.....
```

So, on commits on each branch all ok! Problem is when I merge from `develop` to `master`, or go for a `git flow hotfix` starting on `master` branch.

If I merge from `develop` to `master` the issue is that at some point it will fail the automatic process, and I will have to finish it manually by removing the `boilerplate` folder from git's index, because that's where the issue resides. So I just do `git rm -rf boilerplate/` and all done. This is not such a big issue.

But, if for some reason, I start a new branch just for a hotfix, based on master, either manually or through the `git flow hotfix start XYZ` process, my `boilerplate` directory goes to oblivion when the changes are merged to `develop` as well. All the content in it it's lost... empty, nada, nothing... because, in `master` is ignored completely.

So, I'm looking for a way, if possible, to avoid that issue. Boilerplate for `develop` remains as it should (90% untouched), and on `master` ignored completely, no matter the action performed on a branch. Anyway I can achieve that?

Comment: You didn't give a reason why you have different patterns for `/boilerplate` in `dev` and `master`. Why not simply use the pattern `/boilerplate/` in all branches?

Comment: because that's how I need them. As you can see, in `dev` I am omitting what could be large directories of 3rd party libraries, that constantly change, which I don't need to constantly show in my `git status`. As said, `boilerplate` contains tools (like grunt) needed for the development process.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. Please tell me why the **patterns** have to be different. So far, I don't see why you exclude everything in `master` but only a part in `dev`. Do you need to commit some things below `boilerplate/` when working in `dev`?

Comment: The `boilerplate` directory on dev, contain assets that are being processed by Grunt. Just as `bower_components` indicate, there are `less`, `css`, `javascript` and some other files. And those files, are not needed at all on master, because on master I just have everything needed compiled, ready to go (the `.min` files).

Comment: Why do you need them under version control?

Comment: @AaronDigulla don't get me wrong, but if you would read the comments carefully and/or the details in my question, you would realize that there are files in `boilerplate`, in `develop` branch that are needed and/or common for other contributors. But, I might've not been clear enough about it also, and if so, please forgive me. But still, that's not the issue is not the content of the directory, but the issue mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution might be:

1. Create a new `dev` branch when you find a bug to fix.
2. Change `.gitignore` and modify all the files in `assets/` and `boilerplate/`
3. Commit those changes to the `dev` branch
4. Switch to `master`
5. Merge the branches with `git merge -s ours`

The last step will tell Git: "Those two branches are now merged. There are no differences anymore." but it won't change any files in `master`. That way, all the "prepare for development" steps can be hidden from Git. Now you can switch back to the `dev` branch. When you do the real merge, Git will only consider files changed after the merge with the `ours` strategy.

That said, I think this is an abuse of Git and the build system. For my own projects, I would use this approach:

- I always work in the `dev` branch.
- A build tool creates a distribution (with minified JS, cleaned boilerplate, etc) from this branch.

The result of the build tool is never committed; the tool has to be good enough so I can recreate every release from the development source by checking out an old version.

If I can't create such a build tool for some reason, the second approach is to create a release repo. The last step of the build is then to delete all the files (only on the filesystem, not in Git!) in the release checkout and then copy the new files into it. `git status` will then show me diff between the current and last release.